# Way to order alphanumeric string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, natural-sort

I have a series of model objects with the following values on a column:

- 2018-A-1
- 2018-A-10
- 2018-A-2
- 2018-A-100
- 2018-A-11
- 2018-B-1
- 2018-B-10
- 2018-B-2
- 2018-B-100
- 2018-A-11

I would like to query the db and get the result in alphanumeric order. I would like to obtain the result in this order:

- 2018-A-1
- 2018-A-2
- 2018-A-10
- ...

Instead, I obtain the following order:

- 2018-A-1
- 2018-A-10
- 2018-A-100
- ...

Any smart way to achieve that result directly with active record?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'smartest', but that sort order looks correct, no?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: @Kerby82 : Please clarify - would you like the sorting happen in Ruby (this is what the tags of your post suggest), or would you like the sorting done by the database (this is what the text of your post suggests).

Comment: Have you considered storing the three parts (e.g. `2018`, `A`, `1`) in different columns with appropriate types?

Answer (score 1):

Here I'm re-stating your example data as an array:

```
example_array = %w{2018-A-1 2018-A-10 2018-A-2 2018-A-100 2018-A-11 2018-B-1 2018-B-10 2018-B-2 2018-B-100 2018-A-11}
```

It's not perfectly clear to me what order you're trying to get. If you are trying to sort based only on the digits following the final hyphen, this should work:

```
example_array.sort_by{|e| e.split("-").last.to_i }
```

If you also intend to include the letter before the final number, perhaps this is what you want:

```
example_array.sort_by{|e| [e.split("-")[-2], e.split("-").last.to_i] }
```

Comment: This is a nice solution if the returned data from the query is not big or a selection of the first x from the ordered array is not needed. Otherwise, you will need to implement that logic as a SQL query (harder to maintain or understand).

Comment: Note that the OP wants to _"achieve that result directly with active record"_

Comment: Ah, well, I believe the request for an ActiveRecord solution was edited onto the question after my answer. In fact, I think there might not be a (pure) ActiveRecord solution. As @TarekN.Elsamni says, it will need to include SQL, perhaps the `SUBSTR()` function.